# Webpack dependency handling (Cant resolve '..' )

Tags: webpack

I have an angular 4 project using webpack.
My `package.json` includes `ngx-mqtt` as a devDependency. As far as I know all dependencies should be devDependencies with webpack.

This resulted in an error that `mqtt.js` contained an unexpected # token which I fixed with shebang-loader.

Now I received the error:

> Module not found : error : Can't resolve 'mqtt'

I fixed this by adding mqtt to my `package.json` (which I don't think I would have to to since it is a dependency of `ngx-mqtt`)

Doing this results in:

> Module not found : error : Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate'
>   which is a dependency of websocket-stream which in turn is a dependency of mqtt

This can't be right can it? I can't have to declare of of my libraries dependencies myself.

`package.json`:

```
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
"@angular/common": "4.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
"@angular/core": "4.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
"@angular/http": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
"@angular/router": "4.2.5",
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
"@types/chai": "4.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
"@types/text-encoding": "0.0.32",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"@types/node": "^8.0.34",
"angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"chai": "4.0.2",
"css": "2.2.1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"es6-shim": "0.35.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.11",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "^0.11.2",
"html-loader": "^0.4.5",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"json-loader": "^0.5.7",
"jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "^1.0.4",
"karma": "1.7.0",
"karma-chai": "0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
"ngx-mqtt": "1.15.0",
"preboot": "4.5.2",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
"rxjs": "5.4.2",
"shebang-loader": "^0.0.1",
"style-loader": "^0.18.2",
"text-encoding": "0.6.4",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
"typescript": "^2.5.3",
"url-loader": "^0.5.9",
"webpack": "^2.7.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.1",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.12"
}
```

Comment: Have you installed all the dependencies using npm install?

Comment: I've run npm install multiple times is there any more to it?

Comment: Can you update your post with package.json?

Comment: Modules that are required by your web server should be in production dependencies. So, make sure those are defined properly.

Comment: my webserver does not requre any dependencies everything is packed into a large minified js file for frontend usage only

Comment: Got you..Have you tried deleting the node_modules and reinstalling  dependencies again?

Comment: yes several times

Comment: Have you overwritten [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules)? If you did and forgot to include the default (`["node_modules"]`), it will break nested dependencies. Even though dependencies of dependencies get [hoisted by npm 3+](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3), you should always include the default.

Comment: these are the webpack.config files used by the template I used:
https://github.com/aspnet/templating/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/Angular-CSharp/webpack.config.js
https://github.com/aspnet/templating/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/Angular-CSharp/webpack.config.vendor.js

Comment: Ok since something seemed completely screwed up with my configuration and now face a similar but different problem I will create a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759803/webpack-error-with-mqttjs-in-angular-project-unexpected-character

Answer (score 0):

can you try this in your webpackconfig

`resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['node_modules']
}`

you can also try to put the relative path to your node_modules directly.